Secure WebSocket Connection Fails Between Vue 3 App and .NET 8 Backend (Code: 1006)
I'm encountering a frustrating issue with secure WebSockets in my project. I have a .NET 8.0 backend hosting a Vue 3 web app on localhost:443 using a self-signed development certificate. The web app tries to connect to a WebSocket endpoint (/ws) exposed by the same backend, but the connection fails with a CloseEvent code of 1006.

Observations:

When using WebSocket clients like Postman or Chrome extensions (e.g., "WebSocket Test Client"), the connection works perfectly.
When connecting through the Vue 3 app running on the same host, the WebSocket fails without much explanation.
If I use http, everything works just fine.


Backend Setup:

WebSocket Controller:

[Route("/[controller]")]
public class WsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task Echo()
    {
        if (HttpContext.WebSockets.IsWebSocketRequest)
        {
            using (var webSocket = await HttpContext.WebSockets.AcceptWebSocketAsync())
            {
                var buffer = new byte[1024 * 4];
                var receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(
                    new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);

                while (!receiveResult.CloseStatus.HasValue)
                {
                    await webSocket.SendAsync(
                        new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, 0, receiveResult.Count),
                        receiveResult.MessageType,
                        receiveResult.EndOfMessage,
                        CancellationToken.None);

                    receiveResult = await webSocket.ReceiveAsync(
                        new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer), CancellationToken.None);
                }

                await webSocket.CloseAsync(
                    receiveResult.CloseStatus.Value,
                    receiveResult.CloseStatusDescription,
                    CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }
    }
}


Vue Web App Hosting:

The Vue app is compiled into a /dist folder and served on /webapp:
app.Map("/webapp", false, builder =>
{
    builder.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location), "dist");

        StaticFileOptions clientAppDist = new StaticFileOptions()
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(path)
        };

        builder.UseSpaStaticFiles(clientAppDist);
        spa.Options.DefaultPageStaticFileOptions = clientAppDist;
    });
});

Vue 3 Webapp code:
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from "vue";

const status = ref("disconnected");

let ws: WebSocket | undefined;

function start() {
  if (ws?.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
    ws.close();
    return;
  }

  const url = window.origin.replace(/^http/, "ws") + "/ws";
  ws = new WebSocket(url);
  ws.onopen = () => {
    status.value = "connected";
    ws?.send("Hello from client");
  };
  ws.onmessage = (rec) => {
    console.log("Message received: " + rec);
  };
  ws.onclose = (evt) => {
    status.value = "disconnected";
    console.log("Connection closed", evt);
  };
  ws.onerror = (evt) => {
    status.value = "error";
    console.log("Connection error", status, evt);
  };
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>WS status: {{ status }}</h1>
  <button @click="start">Connect</button>
</template>

What I've Tried:

Verified that the backend works using Postman and Chrome extensions.
Tried also to add localhost to webSocketOptions.AllowedOrigins, with no success.
Used a valid WebSocket URL (ws:// or wss:// depending on the origin).
Checked browser logs; the only hint is a CloseEvent with code 1006.
Using a certificate signed by an internal CA(of which root certificate is added to the Trusted Root CAs), with no success.

Question:
Why does the WebSocket connection fail from the Vue app while working with external clients like Postman? What additional steps should I take to debug or fix this?
